# How and when does MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml get populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a couple of questions related to this file (MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml).

**1)** Can anyone tell me when and how this file is generated?

I know it is generated by the framework to reduce the amount of refection needed when controllers are called.

I also know there are a few internal class in MVC source for working with it, the controller factory `GetControllerType` makes use of them.

**2)** Is there a way to work with it in an application ?

For example if I want to list all the controllers in the application, using this file would mean I do not have to find them all myself via reflection.

It would also be worth knowing how / when it gets updated as the method `GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);` will return your controller type based on what it finds in this file.

Knowing when it gets updated and if you can rely on it could change the way you register controllers from plugins / modules that reside in their own assemblies.

I mainly ask purely out of interest though.

Comment: I've written a complete blog post on this subject right here http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/controller_lookup_and_default_controller_factory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Can anyone tell me when and how this file is generated?

The `DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType` which is invoked on each request calls the  `GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces` method to retrieve the list of available controller types:

```
private Type GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(RouteBase route, string controllerName, HashSet<string> namespaces) {
    ControllerTypeCache.EnsureInitialized(BuildManager);
    ICollection<Type> matchingTypes = ControllerTypeCache.GetControllerTypes(controllerName, namespaces);

    ... more code removed for brevity
}
```

As you can see it does 2 things in the beginning: initialization and retrieving of controller types from the `ControllerTypeCache`.

The `EnsureInitialized` method uses a singleton with double checked locking to ensure that initialization is performed only once for the entire lifetime of the application:

```
public void EnsureInitialized(IBuildManager buildManager) {
    if (_cache == null) {
        lock (_lockObj) {
            if (_cache == null) {
                List<Type> controllerTypes = TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(_typeCacheName, IsControllerType, buildManager);
                var groupedByName = controllerTypes.GroupBy(
                    t => t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.Length - "Controller".Length),
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                _cache = groupedByName.ToDictionary(
                    g => g.Key,
                    g => g.ToLookup(t => t.Namespace ?? String.Empty, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the `_cache` field will be initialized only once if it is null. This will happen on the very first request that hits your site after the application has started by IIS.

The controller types are retrieved using the `TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies` method. So let's look into it:

```
public static List<Type> GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(string cacheName, Predicate<Type> predicate, IBuildManager buildManager) {
    TypeCacheSerializer serializer = new TypeCacheSerializer();

    // first, try reading from the cache on disk
    List<Type> matchingTypes = ReadTypesFromCache(cacheName, predicate, buildManager, serializer);
    if (matchingTypes != null) {
        return matchingTypes;
    }

    // if reading from the cache failed, enumerate over every assembly looking for a matching type
    matchingTypes = FilterTypesInAssemblies(buildManager, predicate).ToList();

    // finally, save the cache back to disk
    SaveTypesToCache(cacheName, matchingTypes, buildManager, serializer);

    return matchingTypes;
}
```

The code is pretty self explanatory:

1. it uses a `TypeCacheSerializer` class to read them from the cache. Internally this serializer loads the file into a `XmlDocument` and then manipulates its elements to extract the types.
2. if nothing is found into the cache an expensive call is made to the `FilterTypesInAssemblies` method that will use reflection to retrieve the controller types from all referenced assemblies.
3. it saves the types to the cache so that next time they are loaded from the cache.

Here's a blog post which also describes the process: http://www.beletsky.net/2011/12/inside-aspnet-mvc-instantiation-of.html

> 2) Is there a way to work with it in an application ?

You are not supposed to work directly with this XML file from your code because its contents and format could change in future versions which would break your code.

I agree though that it would have been nice to be able to take advantage of this feature from our code to improve the performance of otherwise expensive reflection code. I wish the authors of the framework had made this API public.

Unfortunately they haven't, so we could roll our own:

```
public static class ControllerTypeCache
{
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();
    private static Type[] _cache;

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetControllerTypes()
    {
        if (_cache == null)
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (_cache == null)
                {
                    _cache = GetControllerTypesWithReflection();
                }
            }
        }
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(_cache);
    }

    private static Type[] GetControllerTypesWithReflection()
    {
        var typesSoFar = Type.EmptyTypes;
        var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies) 
        {
            Type[] typesInAsm;
            try 
            {
                typesInAsm = assembly.GetTypes();
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex) 
            {
                typesInAsm = ex.Types;
            }
            typesSoFar = typesSoFar.Concat(typesInAsm).ToArray();
        }

        return typesSoFar
            .Where(t => t != null && 
                        t.IsPublic && 
                        !t.IsAbstract && 
                        typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            )
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

> It would also be worth knowing how / when it gets updated as the
>   method GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName); will return
>   your controller type based on what it finds in this file.

This file never gets updated during the whole lifetime of the application. As explained earlier it is created once, when the application starts.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a quick look at the ASP.NET MVC source code, and as far as I can tell, the cache file gets created when something is attempting to read it for the first time. This will typically happen during the start of the application.

ASP.NET MVC contains an internal class `ControllerTypeCache` with a constant string containing the filename. This is the only occurence of "MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml" in the source code.

```
internal sealed class ControllerTypeCache
{
    private const string TypeCacheName = "MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml";
    ...
}
```

This constant is only used in this method of the `ControllerTypeCache` class:

```
public void EnsureInitialized(IBuildManager buildManager)
{
    if (_cache == null)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            if (_cache == null)
            {
                List<Type> controllerTypes = TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(TypeCacheName, IsControllerType, buildManager);
                var groupedByName = controllerTypes.GroupBy(
                    t => t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.Length - "Controller".Length),
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                _cache = groupedByName.ToDictionary(
                    g => g.Key,
                    g => g.ToLookup(t => t.Namespace ?? String.Empty, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it passes the filename to `TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteresTypesFromAssemblies`. This is what that method looks like:

```
public static List<Type> GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(string cacheName, Predicate<Type> predicate, IBuildManager buildManager)
{
    TypeCacheSerializer serializer = new TypeCacheSerializer();

    // first, try reading from the cache on disk
    List<Type> matchingTypes = ReadTypesFromCache(cacheName, predicate, buildManager, serializer);
    if (matchingTypes != null)
    {
        return matchingTypes;
    }

    // if reading from the cache failed, enumerate over every assembly looking for a matching type
    matchingTypes = FilterTypesInAssemblies(buildManager, predicate).ToList();

    // finally, save the cache back to disk
    SaveTypesToCache(cacheName, matchingTypes, buildManager, serializer);

    return matchingTypes;
}
```

As you can see, it tries to read from the cache file. If the reading fails (e.g. because the file doesn't exist yet), a new list of controllertypes is generated and saved in a new version of the cache file.

The `ReadTypesFromCache` method looks like this:

```
internal static List<Type> ReadTypesFromCache(string cacheName, Predicate<Type> predicate, IBuildManager buildManager, TypeCacheSerializer serializer)
{
    try
    {
        Stream stream = buildManager.ReadCachedFile(cacheName);
        if (stream != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                List<Type> deserializedTypes = serializer.DeserializeTypes(reader);
                if (deserializedTypes != null && deserializedTypes.All(type => TypeIsPublicClass(type) && predicate(type)))
                {
                    // If all read types still match the predicate, success!
                    return deserializedTypes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see it uses a `BuildManager` to read the cached file.

This is the only place I can find that reads from or creates the cache file. When navigating through the call hierarchy I end up in that method from either the `DefaultControllerFactory` class or the `AreaRegistration` class.

So I guess the first time any of these classes need the list of controllers in the application, the `GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies` method of the `TypeCacheUtil` class ends up being called. It only generates the cache file when the file cannot be read from. Since this class uses a `BuildManager` to read it, I believe it only generates it when the file is corrupt, missing or when the application is restarted.

After browsing the web, people seem to report that in order to regenerate the MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml file, something like changing and saving the Global.asax or Web.Config file in order to trigger a restart does the trick.

Can you take advantage of this file in your own code? You probably *can*, but you probably *shouldn't*. I'd just use reflection. If you ever face performance problems because of that approach, *then* you can start thinking about caching, and in that case I'd wager it's "safer" to build your own serialized list of controllers and use the inbuilt caching mechanisms of .NET to cache them rather than trying to reuse MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml. It's internal for a reason I guess.